# how to replace space by % in objective c :Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am getting value in search box from user and storing it in NSstring *searchWord;

I want that when user typed let say "Lady Gaga" then I Replace the space with % just like that 
      searchWord=searchbar.text;

```
  now search word has "lady gaga"

 I want to replace it with.
  searchword=@"lady%gaga";
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try this :

```
NSString *newString = [ @"lady gaga" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%"];
```

It should work :-)

Answer (score 1):

`-[NSString replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:]`